# How to put background shapes in ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-constraintlayout, android-shape

I had nested `LinearLayouts` and after reading some doc I tried to switch to `ConstraintLayout`. But I did not find how to insert a view to just display a background.
So far I just set the background on the layout containing the items.

This is what the old nested structure looks like (with more nested items in other sub-layouts):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:gravity="center" >

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     ... some margins and padding
     android:background="@drawable/global_background" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/text_area_background" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center" />
    ...
```

This way I was able to easily set a shape of my own as a background for the different groups of items I displayed.

How can I achieve the equivalent using `ConstraintLayout`?

I understand how I can constrain my items to get organized the same way, and how I could set the backgrounds to align with everything too. But how do I insert a *simple background item*?

Answer (score 1):

I used `ImageView` to display my background and (hardly) found a way to assemble my items inside it.
One problem is that I get a warning `Image without contentDescription`.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="2:5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/global_background" />

    ...

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonValidate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/green_button"
        android:text="@string/validate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/background"
        app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="15:6"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/background"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/upperButton" />
```

But I struggled to put another background inside (itself containing several `TextView`). My constraints were always messing one or the other... I ended up with a nested `ConstraintLayout` which is working fine, probably not the optimal solution but all my other attempts failed.